# Intersect and union of two different list of custom objects with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to get an intersection and union of two `List`s of different types. I have been trying using Java 8 streams because I think this is the easiest way to do it. So far I have failed each time.

I have simplified the code so it can easily be reproduced. I have two objects, `Data1` and `Data2`.

For example:

```
public class Data2 {    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Data2(int id, String name, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

}

public class Data1 {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int amount;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Data1(int id, String name, int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}

public class OutputData {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int amount;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public OutputData(int id, String name, String type, int amount) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

They have similar fields.. I need to intersect them based on ID (intersect) and store them in an output (union?) of type `OutputData`.

Example of a main type:

```
List<Data2> listOfData2 = new ArrayList<Data2>();

    listOfData2.add(new Data2(10501, "JOE"  , "Type1"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(10603, "SAL"  , "Type5"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(40514, "PETER", "Type4"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(59562, "JIM"  , "Type2"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(29415, "BOB"  , "Type1"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(61812, "JOE"  , "Type9"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(98432, "JOE"  , "Type7"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(62556, "JEFF" , "Type1"));
    listOfData2.add(new Data2(10599, "TOM"  , "Type4"));


List<Data1> listOfData1 = new ArrayList<Data1>();

    listOfData1.add(new Data1(10501, "JOE"    ,3000000));
    listOfData1.add(new Data1(10603, "SAL"    ,6225000));
    listOfData1.add(new Data1(40514, "PETER"  ,2005000));
    listOfData1.add(new Data1(59562, "JIM"    ,3000000));
    listOfData1.add(new Data1(29415, "BOB"    ,3000000));
```

Here is one of my best attempts at this, with no success and lots of errors:

```
List<OutputData> od = 
  listOfData1.stream()
             .flatMap(x -> listOfData2.stream()
                                      .filter(y -> x.getId().equals(y.getId()))
             .map(y -> new OutputData(x.getId(), x.getName(), y.getType(), x.getAmount()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This should return a `List<OutputData>` that has one entry of ID 10603, name SAL and all other fields populated.

Comment: Are you using Guava?

Comment: I am not, but I would be open to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it, but in the example there are 5 records in each list that have same ids.

```
List<OutputData> result = listOfData1.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> listOfData2.stream()
                .filter(y -> x.getId() == y.getId())
                .map(y -> new OutputData(y.getId(), x.getName(), y.getType(), x.getAmount())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I just realized my test cases were wrong. I am going to test this out and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some pseudo code:

```
declare list 3 (type data3)

for i = length of list 1
  for j = length of list 2
    if list1[i].getid == list2[j].getid
      new data3 object with all relevant fields
      add to list 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code. I am able to do it no problem with regular loops. I wanted to do it using java 8 streams though

Comment: No problem. I was wondering why you were using a more complicated solution than necessary. Cheers!